# Visual Studio Debug Console Not Printing Everything

Tags: c#, debugging, console

I am following along a course in c# and despite my code being identical, it does not completely print the program. For example if I have Console.WriteLine("Hello") 5 times, only 4 of them will print.

Just now I am trying to cube some integers and instead of printing correctly it shows me "le when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . ." The word "le" is cut off and everything before that doesn't show.

Also when I run the console , the window opens up as small as possible and I have to manually change the size to see what it printed.

I purposefully added some extra WriteLines, only the last 2 will show however

```
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string characterName = "Tom";
            int characterAge;
            characterAge = 25;


                Console.WriteLine("There was once a man named " + characterName);
                Console.WriteLine("He was " + characterAge + " years old.");
                characterName = "Mike";
                Console.WriteLine("He really liked the name " + characterName);
                Console.WriteLine("But didn't like being " + characterAge);
                Console.WriteLine("But didn't like being " + characterAge);
                Console.WriteLine("But didn't like being " + characterAge);
                Console.WriteLine("But didn't like being " + characterAge);
                Console.WriteLine("But didn't like being " + characterAge);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you run your program through CMD does the same lack-of-output behavior occur? (`dotnet run MyProjectName`)

Comment: Can you show your code please? If you put a breakpoint on your code before each Console.Writeline and F10 to go to the next line, does it show then? Do you have a Console.Readline at the end to make sure you get chance to view everything? It's possible your program has run so quickly you aren't seeing anything and that console you are seeing is from an old session.

Comment: @HockeyJ The above code that I posted only shows ("But didn't like being" + characterAge) twice and ignores everything before it. It is still storing the variables but not printing everything

Comment: @HockeyJ Yes using f10 to cycle through each line will show it

Comment: Either the number of rows in your cmd window is only showing 4 rows or you are not running the latest version of your application.  To change rows use File Explorer and go to c:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe.  Right click and select Pin to Start.  Then find cmd.exe in Start and right click.  On Options tab increase the Buffer size.  On the Layout Tab increase the height of the Screen Buffer Size the the Windows size.  This will give you more rows on the screen.

Comment: @gunr2171 Negative, all of the strings will be printed but in Visual Studio 2019 output will only print last 2 lines .

Comment: @MarlonGonzalez . Did you get anywhere here? Maybe closing visual studio, deleting the bin/obj folders then retrying might help. If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.